# Strange grain over transparency on Unity Linux build

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, graphics, transparency

OK, so I'm in the beginnings of a new project on Patreon. This project is two weeks old, and runs beautifully on Windows and WebGL; and it runs functionally on Linux, but in spite of having a very good system I'm getting a weird problem with semitransparent overlays.

Example:

[image]

You'll see a sort of dot-matrix like grain over the transparent overlay that is becoming the pause menu? That isn't supposed to be there. Additionally, I've had something similar going on in the upper-left corner over the thermometer in the past.

I have no idea what's causing this. Hardware is an nVIDIA GTX 950 GPU, with updated drivers; and my processor is an AMD FX-8300 8-Core. No other performance issues or strain, though I have noticed that certain jumping platforms are flat-out removed from the game on low graphics quality, which I will need to look into. (Physics also gets a little wonky, so I might just remove those levels; this is meant for reasonably modern machines.) Everything else renders correctly, so it is likely something involving my cameras (one for scene, second child camera for UI), or my materials.

Settings for the build were (x86 + x86_64), this problem occurs on both versions, and other than that, defaults, aside from my company name. The only "preview" package I'm using is for post-processing. I use both real time and baked lighting in the scene.

In summary, that's a game built for Windows x64, WebGL, and Linux (x86 + x64); with dual cameras (one for scene, one for UI), and no other graphical or functional issues. Any ideas as to what could be causing this grain, and how I could potentially remove it?

Comment: What is the problem or question? I can't seem to find it in there (other than *"any ideas"*).

Comment: @jww I'ld say that strange grain on the transparent panel. Could it be a softshadow thing?

Comment: @jww My question is what's causing the grain. Before I can fix it, I need to understand what's causing it. It looked fine in the editor; but the Linux build has this weirdness going on.

Comment: @derHugo Interesting. Could you explain what you mean by that? What do soft shadows have to do with it? To be clear, the items that have the grain are exclusively UI elements. Additionally, I'm noticing a sort of "tracing" of the scenery in its presence as the main camera pans.

Comment: @jww I've edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: Looks like a sampling problem, but I have no way of knowing if it's something in your code or not.

Comment: I attempted a few workarounds, including using a fully opaque background for the UI skeleton, and disabling post-processing. The fully opaque background did nothing; disabling post-processing worked, but this game is post-proc heavy and that's no good in the long term. I'm filing a formal bug report with Unity, as it's safe to say I'm doing this right and the issue may be on their end.
If it's resolved in a future build or post-proc release with no further action on my part, I may close this question. Otherwise, I'll keep everybody informed.